# Navbar anchors not directing correctly with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may just be me being picky but I have a little problem which is kind of difficult to discribe. On my practice site [here](http://amdiamonddesigns.000space.com/), the navigation bar (which I finally got working pretty well) has an issue where once the window is resized below the necessary width to turn into a dropdown, the site no longer scrolls to the top of each section. Instead it seems to scroll to the top of the section minus/plus the height of the menu drop down. Since I've chosen to have the menu collapse after choosing a link, I think the ideal solution would be to have the page scroll after the menu is fully collapsed. Perhaps that will help. Any suggestions on how to make this happen? You should be able to see in the source the 'scripts.js' file what I've done.

EDIT: Upon further inspection I see that this problem only occurs after the page is reloaded while the navigation bar is already fixed to the top (so anywhere below the 'work' section). **I wish I could demonstrate better with screen capture but the best way to replicate for me seems to be to try the links after reload at various positions along the page.**
For example- if you reload the page while at the bottom, then try to you the drop down menu you get this scenario in the pictures provided:

**Image 1:**
[image]

**Image 2:**
[image]

Comment: Not quite sure i'm seeing what you are describing (btw very nice demo site).  I think screenshots highlighting the target issues would be helpful.  Most people here will be reluctant to post answers without some sort of code as well.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the differing offset for the top navbar? Could be wrong though...

Comment: Please place relevant code and HTML in your question (not just links).  Having only external references to code that is required for the question is not permitted here at SO.

Comment: In fact, if you refresh the anchor points on resize you may not have the issue. My advice would be to remove the plugins for scrolling since you already have Bootstrap 3.2.0 loaded and use it's ScrollSpy function instead.

Comment: It's not simply on resize. You can see the same issue by reloading the full page while at the bottom then using the menu to reach another point. The link does not point to the correct position of the anchor. You have to do a total refresh however.

Answer (score 0):

On resize use a `.off()` statement to remove the events and add them again with `.on()`. The problem is that when you attach the events it uses fixed points on the page, but when you resize the browser those points are no longer at the right place on the page. By doing this you'll update the place where the browser scrolls to.

For example:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    // remove whaetver events you have attached
    $('#navbar').off('event names go here');

    // Re-attach the events
    $('#navbar').on('event names go here');
});
```